# Linear Transformations, how do i verify if something is one?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let T: $R^3 \to R^3$ be a linear transformation defined by $T([x y z]) = [x-y+2z, 2y+z, -x-2y+2z]$
How do I verify it is a linear transformation?
How do I show that $T(cX+Y)=cT(X)+T(Y)$?
If $u=[a\space b\space c] \in R^3$, what are the conditions on $a, b, c$ that the vector be in the range of $T$?

Comment: Your title should be in body. So that viewer can understand your question.

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 2):

Let $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ and $v_1,v_2 \in \mathbb{R}^3$. Generally, we will say that $v_i = (x_i,y_i,z_i)$, where $i$ just refers to some number index and $v_i \in \mathbb{R}^3$. This is just setting up notation for our check.

Now, you defined a map $T: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ as follows:

$$T(v) = (x-y+2z,2y+z,-x-y+2z)$$

So, this is just an exercise in:

1. Using the definition of a linear map
2. Using the definition of our map

We need to check two things:

1. $T(v_1+v_2) = T(v_1)+T(v_2)$
2. $T(\alpha \cdot v) = \alpha \cdot T(v)$

I'll do the second one for you. Consider:

$$T(\alpha \cdot v) = (\alpha x - \alpha y + 2(\alpha z),2(\alpha y) + \alpha z,-\alpha x -\alpha y + 2(\alpha z))$$

Now, you can literally just pull the $\alpha$ out and we have:

$$T(\alpha \cdot v) = \alpha \cdot (x-y+2z,2y+z,-x-y+2z)$$

This follows from the definition of scalar multiplication in $\mathbb{R}^3$. However, that right-hand side is just the same as $\alpha \cdot T(v)$. Therefore:

$$T(\alpha \cdot v) = \alpha \cdot T(v)$$

Can you check if the other condition holds on your own? :D Let me know if you need any assistance.

Answer (score 1):

show that T is equivalent to left multiplication by a matrix.It is alos linear transformation(why). Here we have

\begin{align}
T(x, y, z) &= (x -y+2z,2y+z , -x-2y+2z) \\ 
&= x(1, 0, -1) + y(-1, 2, -2) + z(0, 1, 2) \\
&= 
\begin{bmatrix}
1  & 0  & -1 \\
-1 & 2  & -2 \\
0 & 1& 2 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x \\
y \\
z \\
\end{bmatrix} \\
\end{align}
write it as $TX=AX$ 
Can you check that it is linear transformation.